# Does giving access to Apex class is required for a Permission set of Visual Force Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, permissions

I have created a VF page. Now, i want to give that VF Page access to my child user.

I have included VF page in permission set and my question is, is it necessary to include Apex class too to make my page work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to include the classes as well.

Once a user has access to a Visualforce page they also have access to all of it's dependancies, this is covered in the [Visualforce Page Security documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_page_level_security.htm).

> Permission for a Visualforce page is checked at the top level only. Once users can access a page, they can execute all Apex that’s associated with the page. This includes:
>
> - The controller for the page and any Apex classes called from the controller class.
> - Any extension classes for the page and any Apex called from an extension.
> - Any Apex classes associated with custom components within the page.
> - Any classes associated with the page through the use of apex:include or apex:composition.
>
> For example, if page A depends on a controller that calls an Apex class B, and a user has access only to page A but not class B, the user can still execute the code in page A. Likewise, if a Visualforce page uses a custom component with an associated controller, security is only checked for the controller associated with the page, not for the controller associated with the component.